model is flickering in the autodesk forge viewet
I am using autodesk forge viewer and  loading some ifc files in the viewer.The model is loading but when i choose first person to walk in the model the model is flickering .Is there any way to get ou of the problem
enter image description here  example if iam loading a building model when i select first person to walk in or inside the model the model is flickering .
I want to get out of this flickering issue.Even after disabling the Progressive Display in the settings of the viewer

Could you please provide more details? Perhaps a video showing the issue? Progressive rendering can cause flickering if the model is too large but with the progressive rendering disabled, this behavior should go away.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2aBkSxGTusw
please find the  video .I have shared the issue that iam getting .

Thank you @voltus. This looks like it could potentially be some z-fighting issue, or a problem with culling (objects being excluded from the renderer even though they should be rendered). If you could share the IFC file with us (confidentially, only for internal debugging) via aps.help@autodesk.com, we'd be happy to investigate the issue on our side.

If you do share the file with us, please include additional information about your current setup - what is the viewer version, what kinds of customizations you've made to it, whether the issue can be reproduced in other APS apps such as https://viewer.autodesk.com/, etc.
